# Immutable dictionaries in Haskell

Tags: code-golf, data-structures, haskell

You need to implement immutable dictionaries using only functions without any other data types (custom or built-in).
The dictionary must be indexed by any data type of class Eq and contain values of arbitrary type, but all the values in a dictionary should be of the same type.

Here are some examples of usage:

```
dict `access` True -- returns value of key True
dict `access` "y"  -- returns value of key "y"
(update "x" 10 dict) `access` "x" -- returns 10 for any dict
```

Comment: This is a site for programming contests, and contests need criteria to select the winners. What makes one correct implementation better than another?

Comment: The amount of code is the criteria (less is better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update key1 value obj = \key2 -> if key2 == key1 then value else obj key2
access = id
```

Given the above definitions, your examples should work. Also, you can define an empty dictionary as `const x` where `x` is the default value for keys not in the dictionary.